# Jquery datatable Hidden column showing after calling another script .how can i hide the column specified permanently?

Tags: jquery, datatables

My table is

```
<table id="EmployeesTable" style="width: 100%;" class="grid-table06 border-one">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="80%" align="left" valign="middle">Name</th>
            <th width="20%" align="left" valign="middle">Department</th>
            <th>Id</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

My script as follows

```
$(function () {
    $(".switchDate").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("rel");
        fetchEmployeedetails(id);
    });

    fetchEmployeedetails(@model.Id); //on load

    function fetchEmployeedetails(id) {
        $("#EmployeesTable").dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/Employees/FetchDetails?Deptid=" + id + "&thresholdLow=4&threshold=100",
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bDestroy": true,
            "aaSorting": [[1, 'desc']],
            "asStripClasses": ['color01', 'color03'],

            "aoColumnDefs": [{
                "aTargets": [2],
                "bVisible": false
            }, {
                "aTargets": [1],
                "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                    return "<a href='#showemployees' rel='" + oObj.aData[2] + "'></a>";
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

On load it works fine not showing the hidden "Id" column but in case when I choose the id by switchDate on click function it causes the hidden column to be visible for second.

How can I hide the column permanently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialisation of dataTable (`.dataTable(...)`) should only happen once, right after page load event. Since then, `.fnDraw()` takes responsibility to update it.

From [dataTables official website](http://datatables.net/api):

> Note for those using server-side processing: A number of the API functions make the assumption that data storage it done on the client-side, rather than the server-side. As such functions such as fnAddData and fnDeleteRow will not effect the data held on your database. Indeed DataTables does not know if you are even using a database! As such, you must make the required calls to the server to manipulate your data as required, and then simply redraw the table (fnDraw) to view the new data.

Read more here: http://datatables.net/api#fnDraw

So you have to change your code like this:

```
$(function () {

   dataTableInitialisation();

   $(".switchDate").click(function () {
       var ajaxUrl = "/Employees/FetchDetails?Deptid=" + $(this).attr("rel") + "&thresholdLow=4&threshold=100";
       fetchEmployeedetails(ajaxUrl);
   });
});

fetchEmployeedetails(ajaxSource){
    var oSettings = myOTable.fnSettings();
    oSettings.sAjaxSource = ajaxSource;
    myOTable.fnDraw();
} 

function dataTableInitialisation() {
    myOTable = $("#EmployeesTable").dataTable({
          "bProcessing": true,
          "bServerSide": true,
          "sAjaxSource": "/Employees/FetchDetails?Deptid=" + @model.Id + "&thresholdLow=4&threshold=100",
          "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
          "bDestroy": true,
          "aaSorting": [[1, 'desc']],
          "asStripClasses": ['color01', 'color03'],
          "aoColumnDefs": [{
                  "aTargets": [2],
                  "bVisible": false
                  }, {
                  "aTargets": [1],
                  "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                  return "<a href='#showemployees' rel='" + oObj.aData[2] + "'></a>";
                  }
           }]
       });
   }
});
```

By the way I suggest to use `aoData.push()` to send more data to server rather than changing `sAjaxSource`. Here is more info about sending extra data to the server:
http://datatables.net/usage/server-side#fnServerParams

Comment: @SreenathPlakkat- I cannot understand your question, please create a new question in details and give me the link to read it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look this example: http://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html

```
function fnShowHide( iCol ) {
    /* Get the DataTables object again - this is not a recreation, just a get of the object */
    var oTable = $('#EmployeesTable').dataTable();

    var bVis = oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[iCol].bVisible;
    oTable.fnSetColumnVis( iCol, bVis ? false : true );
}
```

Than you just call `dnShowHide(columnPosition);`

Comment: hi now also shows the hidden column fraction of seconds after switchdate